# Show image using OpenCV in Python on a Raspberry Pi terminal

Tags: python, linux, opencv, terminal, raspberry-pi

I get a gtk-WARNING when trying:

cv2.imshow("WindowName", image)

I'm using this to watch a live stream one frame at a time. Are there any alternative libraries I could use? I tried several other options like PIL and Tkinter as well as wand, but could get none of them to work for various different reason.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a windowing system to display images using `imshow`.
(That can be enabled in settings running `sudo raspi-config`)

If you absolutely, positively need to display images without using a windowing system, consider providing an html/web interface. Two options that come to mind when serving a web interface are:

1. Creating an HTTP video stream (serve the output image as if it's an IP camera, kind of)
2. Stream the output matrix as a jpg blob via websockets

Comment: Do you have any idea if it's possible with another library that doesn't require a window? I know images can be displayed with tools like FBI or stream a camera in Python from PiCamera.

Comment: That's a good point actually. I'm not an expert on this, but I have a hunch fbi and the PiCamera preview write straight to the video chip's buffer. If fbi has a library, or there's a similar python library capable of displaying straight to the GPU, you should try that. (In short: 1. find a library that allows you display an image via GPU in Python (without windowing). 2. convert the opencv/numpy pixel array to the image format this library expects, then pass your data to it). Be aware, this would be visible with on a screen (but not using ssh)